# Equilibrium points of a family of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

> Give an example of a family of differential equations $x'=f_a(x)$ for which there are no equilibrium points if $a<0$; a single equilibrium point if $a=0$ and no equilibrium points if $a>0$.

I have an  example of differential equations but it only has a single equilibrium point if $a=1/4$,2 equilibrium points if $a<1/4$ and 0 equilibrium points if $a>1/4$.

$x'=x^2+y, y'=x-y+a$,

The example above can help to solve the first exercise? If yes, how?

I feel lost, any kind of help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the family of differential equations on $\Bbb R$:

$\dot x = x^2 + a^2 = f_a(x); \tag 1$

for $a \ne 0$,

$\dot x > 0, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 2$

for $a = 0$, the equation (1) reduces to

$\dot x = x^2, \tag 3$

which has precisely one equilibrium at $x = 0$.

A similar example in two dimensions is given by

$f_a(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} y^2 + a^2 \\ x^2 + a^2 \end{pmatrix}, \tag 4$

that is,

$\dot x = y^2 + a^2, \tag 5$

$\dot y = x^2 + a^2. \tag 6$

Not totally sure at the moment how your example system might help with your problem, though you might be able to modify it so that it has no zeroes when $a < 1/4$, whilst leaving the number of of equilibria for values of $a \ge 1/4$ undisturbed.

Comment: For the first family, if $a>0$, $x^2+a^2=0$ implies $x=\sqrt {-a^2}$ so there won't be equilibrium points?

Comment: If $a \ne 0$, $a^2 >0$ so $\sqrt{-a^2}$ is imaginary.  I was assuming you were working in $\Bbb R$, so I eliminated this as a possible solution.  I mean, there is no real $x$ with $x^2 = -a^2 < 0$.

Comment: yes, it's in $\mathbb R$. Are there other solutions for $x^2+a^2=0$?

Comment: As long as $a \ne 0$, there are no other solutions.

Comment: oh yes I was confused with the a>0 and a<0, if a>0 then there's no equilibrium points.

Comment: no, I think I messed up things, the exercise say 4 equilibrium points if $a>0$ and no equilibrium points if $a<0$. 

Comment: Since I used $a^2$, and $a^2 > 0$ for real $a$, there are no equilibria even when $a < 0$.  Only when $a = 0$.  That's why I chose $a^2$, to make the example easy.

Comment: Well, that makes things completely different!

Comment: yes, what do I do now, do I edit the question or do I post a new question?

Comment: If I were you I'd post a new question, since it, and the answers, will be somewhat different.  Just make sure you stress the number of equilibria you want for differing values of $a$.

Comment: Let me know if you post it.  You can do so by posting a comment @Robert Lewis.